# Erro de consulta Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, sql-server

Eu criei um projeto no XAMPP onde está funcionando perfeitamente. Mas ao hospedar no 000webhost, ele emite esse erro.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
/storage/ssd4/099/13917099/public_html/rel/rel_servico.php on line 18
```

Esse é meu codigo:

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];
include('../conexao.php');
$query = "select o.id, o.cliente, o.motorista, o.placa, o.servico, o.dtabertura, o.status,
       c.nome, c.cnpj, c.estadual, c.social, c.telefone, c.email
        from orcamentos as o 
       INNER JOIN 
       clientes as c 
     on o.cliente = c.nome
      where o.id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

while ($res_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  //Aqui onde emite o erro.
    $dtabertura2 = implode('/', array_reverse(explode('-', $res_1["dtabertura"])));
    $servico2 = implode('<hr>', (explode(';', $res_1["servico"])));
?>
<div class="cabecalho">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">  
          <img id="logo" src="../img/logo_origin.fw.png" width="270px">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h3 class="titulo"><b>WP DA SILVA - ME</b></h3> 
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="cabecath"> CNPJ: 09.500.074/0001-61 </th>
                <th class="cabecath"> IE: 06.362337-4 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cabecath"> Rua Josias Inojosa de Oliveira, 5500 </td>
                <td class="cabecath"> Juazeiro do Norte - Ceará </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cabecath"> Bairro: Santa Rosa </td>
                <td class="cabecath"> CEP: 63045-010 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cabecath"> Distrito Industrial do Cariri </td>
                <td class="cabecath">Tele-vendas: (88) 99901-9397 </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cabecath">Contato: (88) 98826-1075 </td>
                <td class="cabecath"> E-mail: wecarrocerias@yahoo.com.br </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div >
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <big>Orçamento N° <?php echo $id ?></big>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <big>DATA: <?php echo $dtabertura2 ?></big>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="pdefine"><b>Nome do Cliente: </b><?php echo $res_1["cliente"]; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="pdefine"><b>CNPJ/CPF: </b><?php echo $res_1["cnpj"]; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="pdefine"><b>R. Social: </b><?php echo $res_1["social"]; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="pdefine"><b>I. Estadual: </b><?php echo $res_1["estadual"]; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="pdefine"><b>Motorista: </b><?php echo $res_1["motorista"]; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="pdefine"><b>Telefone: </b><?php echo $res_1["telefone"]; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="porcamentos"><b> Serviços da placa: <?php echo $res_1["placa"]; ?> </b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col" >Serviços a Prestar</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <br>
                    <td scope="row" colspan="2"><br><?php echo $servico2; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <th scope="col">Status: <?php echo $res_1["status"]; ?></th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    <div class="footer">      
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema pode ser na conexão com o banco. Checa se os dados de acesso estão corretos. (Não postar os dados de acesso aqui para que ninguém se aproveite disso).

Depois que você checar, usa um `var_dump($result)` para ver o que essa variável está retornando.

Outra dica. Coloca isso no início do seu código para que ele não quebre caso não exista o parâmetro id na query string:

```
if(!empty($_GET('id')) {
 //Todo o resto do código aqui
}
```